# How call a function like this $(a()) in another function?

Tags: jquery

I have function called `xyz`. How can I call this function from another called `a`?

```
$(function xyz() {    
  sum(1 + 2);    
});

function b() {
  xyz();
}
```

Comment: with out using $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: Just define the function outside of `$()`?

Comment: Given the JS in the question, you cannot call `xyz` from anywhere as it's only defined within the scope of a jQuery object - which in itself makes absolutely no sense. It's equivalent to a document.ready handler. If you want to make the content of `xyz()` within the scope of other functions, move it to its own declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your question, albeit a little overkill for the situation.

```js
// here we are extending jQuery with a new function
$.extend({
  sum: function() {
    return 1 + 2;
  }
});

// here's our function outside jQuery
function abc() {
  // we call the custom jQuery function
  // and save the result in a var
  var sum = $.sum();

  // we display the result in the DOM
  $("#result").append(sum);
}

// this is where the function is really invoked
abc();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  The result is:
</div>
```